# What is the preferred way to a add a citation suggestion to python packages?

Tags: python, citations

How should developers indicate how users should cite the package, other than on the documentation?

R packages return the preferred citation using `citation("pkg")`.

I can think of `pkg.CITATION`, `pkg.citation` and `pkg.__citation__`.  Are there others?  If there is no preferred way (which seems to be the case to me as I did not find anything on python.org), what are the pros and cons of each?

Comment: I am not aware of this in Python. I mean there is `__name__` and `__doc__` but they are not for that kind of R citation.

Comment: Yeah, in the end it's probably a question of convention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I opted for the dunder option.  Only the dunder option (`__citation__`) makes clear, that this is not a normal variable needed for runtime.

Yes, dunder strings should not be used inflationary because python might use them at a later time.  But if python is going to use `__citation__`, then it will be for a similar purpose.  Also, I deem the relative costs higher with the other options.